# delphi prism (.net) compiler

Tags: .net, delphi, delphi-prism, oxygene

when i try to compile my application in delphi prism, i got these errors

> C:\Users\Burak\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project1\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Main.pas(6,3) : Error : (PE17) Namespace "Windows" does not exist or has no public types
>   C:\Users\Burak\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project1\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Main.pas(7,3) : Error : (PE17) Namespace "Tlhelp32" does not exist or has no public types

am i doing wrong?

> uses
>     Windows,
>     Tlhelp32,
>     System.Drawing,
>     System.Collections,
>     System.Collections.Generic,
>     System.Linq,
>     System.Windows.Forms,
>     System.Windows,
>     System.ComponentModel;

i use 2009 delphi prism, small answers can solve my problem (also i think my problem is stupid, but i can not use CreateRemoteThread, and WriteProcessMemory w/o it).

Best Regards,
Burak TAMTURK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The units (namespaces in .net) Windows and Tlhelp32 are not part of [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism) (.Net), they exist only in Delphi Win32, the first thing you must do, to compile your project is to remove these namespaces in the header of your code. Then you can use [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712982%28VS.71%29.aspx) (Platform Invocation Services) to calling Win32 functions and other unmanaged APIs from managed code (.Net).

I recommend you see these links

- http://www.pinvoke.net/
- [Delphi Prism Wiki](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Main_Page)

Bye.